# Creating array of struct dynamically in golang

Tags: go

I try to create a generic function that accepts any struct value and create a array of that struct type. Here is the code I tried. But I get the error "t is not a type". How can I implement this.

```
    type RegAppDB struct {
    nm   string
    data []interface{}
}

func CreateRegTable(tbl string, rec interface{}) RegAppDB {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(rec)
    fmt.Println(t)
    return RegAppDB{"log", []t}
}
```

Comment: no I need an array of interfaces. What I need data is to hold an array of struct values.

Comment: CreateRegTable creates a struct and returns it. There is another function then would add into data array. Posted the full code implemented below.

Comment: RegAppDB contains an element data for which the data type is not known at compile time, so its declared as []interface{}.  What I want function CreateRegTable to do is to use the run time type of function parameter rec to create a variable of RegAppDB with field data as an array of run time type of rec. What I undersatnd from comments is this is not possible in go?

Answer (score 4):

Go does not support generics, and any attempt to do something like that is not going to work out well. In your specific case, there are a couple of key problems:

- You cannot use a variable as a type. Go is compile-time static typed, so anything that gets type information at runtime (i.e. `reflect.TypeOf`) happens too late to use the way you're trying to do it.
- Equally important, your struct's field is of type `[]interface{}`, which means *the only type you can use for that field* is `[]interface{}`. `[]string`, for example, is a different type, and cannot be assigned to that field.

Answer (score 2):

I took another route. Need some beautification. But this works. So now data is an array of interface and from calling function I pass pointer to structure variables to Save function.

```
    type RegAppDB struct {
    nm   string
    data []interface{}
    cnt  int
}

// CreateRegTable creates a data structure to hold the regression result
func CreateRegTable(tbl string) *RegAppDB {
    return &RegAppDB{tbl, make([]interface{}, 20), 0}
}

// Save implements saving a record Regression application DB
func (rga *RegAppDB) Save(rec interface{}) error {
    rga.data[rga.cnt] = rec
    rga.cnt++
    return nil
}

// Show implements showing the regression table
func (rga *RegAppDB) Show() error {
    fmt.Println(rga.cnt)
    for i := 0; i <= rga.cnt; i++ {
        fmt.Println(rga.data[i])
    }
    return nil
}

// Compare compares two regression table for equality
func (rga *RegAppDB) Compare(rgt *RegAppDB) bool {
    return reflect.DeepEqual(rga, rgt)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done for a generic type. If there are a fixed number of possible types, then you can do something like the following:

```
type RegAppDB struct {
    nm   string
    data interface{}
}

func CreateRegTable(rec interface{}) RegAppDB {
    switch rec.(type) {
    case int:
        return &RegAppDB{"log", []int{}}
    case string:
        return &RegAppDB{"log", []string{}}
    }
    return nil
}
```

Note: Your `data` in `RegAppDB` should be of type `interface{}` since `[]int` implements `interface{}` but not `[]interface{}`